# Node.js Update Form for CRUD APP

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The form updates but only updates the first entry in my database. It does not update the entry of the specified id.

This is my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDB');
var dbSchema = mongoose.Schema({
objID : String,
productName : String,
price : String,
quantity: Number
});
var Document = mongoose.model('Document', dbSchema);
```

The app.post Document.update is not creating the document on the specified id. When the information is posted through my form, the update takes place on the first db entry.

```
app.get('/update', function(req, res,) {
res.render('update', { title: 'Express' });
});

app.post('/updated/',
function(req, res) {
        Document.update({
            objID : req.body.id_name,
            productName : req.body.product_name,
            price : req.body.price_name,
            quantity: req.body.quantity_name
        }, function(err, obj) {
            if (!err) {
                res.redirect('/update');}
            else {
                res.send(err)
            }
        });
    });
```

I have also tried these two methods.

```
app.post('/updated',
function(req, res) {
    Document.findOneAndUpdate({objID: req.params.objID}, req.body, {new: true},
        (err, obj) => {
            if (!err) {
                res.redirect('/update');
            }
            else {
                res.send(err)
            }
        });
});


app.post('/updated/',
function (req,res) {
    Document.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.objID, {$set: req.body}, function (err, product) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send('Product udpated.');
    });
});
```

If anyone can just give the last nudge to assist me i would truly appreciate it.

And this is my update.pug file.

```
doctype html
head
meta(charset='utf-8')
meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
title Superb Grocery IS
link(rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='stylesheets/style.css')
script(type='text/javascript' src='javascripts/validate.js')
.main-nav
ul.nav
    li.name Superb Grocery IS
    li
        a(href='index') Home
    li
        a(href='listing') Listing
    li
        a(href='entry') Add
    li
        a(href='update') Update
    li
        a(href='delete') Delete
header
#wrapperr
    h1(align='center' style='color:blueviolet') Update Products
    form(name='form3' action='/updated' method='post' style='margin-top: 
20px')
        input(name='_method', value='PUT', type='hidden')
        table#table2(align='center' border='3')
            tr
                td
                    label(for='entry_id') ID:
                td
                    input#entry_id(type='text' name='id_name' pattern='^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{5}$' placeholder='RWS35O' onblur='alphanumeric(this)' required='')
            tr
                td
                    label(for='entry_product') Product:
                td
                    input#entry_product(type='text' name='product_name' onblur='letpattern(this)' required='')
            tr
                td
                    label(for='entry_price') Price:
                td
                    input#entry_price(type='text' name='price_name' placeholder='9999 OR 9999.99' onblur='price(this)' required='')
            tr
                td
                    label(for='entry_quantity') Quantity:
                td
                    input#entry_quantity(type='text' name='quantity_name' placeholder='9999' pattern='[0-9]' onblur='numeric(this)' required='')
            tr
                td(colspan='2' align='center')
                    button.reset(type='reset' value='Reset') Reset
                    button.update_btn(type='submit' value='Submit') Update
```

Comment: req.params.objID will be undefined in your post route as you don’t have that specified in the update url route i.e app.post(‘/:objID/update’)

Comment: That did not work, it returns a 404 error.

Comment: You have to read the mongoose official document before start coding, http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update . The `update` function required 2 params: condition and obj, you do not have `condition`, thus your system does not know what record must be update

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the mongoose official document before start coding, http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update . The `update` function required 2 params: condition and obj, you do not have `condition`, thus your system does not know what record must be update. I see you want to update `objID` (???? :| :/), in your case you have to keep old `objID` to update object what you want to update.

```
Document.update({objID: req.body.old_id_name}, {
            objID : req.body.id_name,
            productName : req.body.product_name,
            price : req.body.price_name,
            quantity: req.body.quantity_name
        }, function(err, obj) {
            if (!err) {
                res.redirect('/update');}
            else {
                res.send(err)
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Javascripttech old_id_name is the objId of your row what you want to update, you can store it in everywhere, in my example code, the old id has been stored in a hidden field of html form, but my favorite for this case is `path parameter`

Comment: Yes, I have read through documentation in many programming languages but I am new to mongoose and Node and have spent the past two days reading through documentation on this issue. Please read my above edit to see the many ways I have tried to update. If you can help me with either three of the app post up there I would be grateful. As for old_id_name, When I place the old id name with that parameter in the form it does not work. How can I use the right parameter. Your instructions were not clear.

Comment: @Javascripttech You can read more about RESTful or any CRUD examples by nodejs.  Do not follow me: You need a input tag in your html form to fill old_id like this `input#entry_id(type='text' name='old_id_name' pattern='^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{5}$' placeholder='RWS35O' onblur='alphanumeric(this)' required='' text='What do you want to change?')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const User = require('../models/user')
const jwt = require('../helpers/jwt')

module.exports = class {
  static register(req, res, next) {
    let user = {
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    }
    User.create(user)
      .then(result => {
        res.status(201).json(result)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        next(err)
      })
  }

  static login(req, res, next) {
    let user = {
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    }
    // console.log(user);

    User.findOne(user)
      .then(userLogin => {
        let token = jwt.generateToken({
          email: userLogin.email,
          id: userLogin._id
        })
        res.status(200).json({ token: token })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        ;(err.statusCode = 400), (err.message = 'Email or Password is invalid')
        next(err)
      })
  }

  static getUser(req, res, next) {
    try {
      let user = {
        _id: req.body.user._id,
        name: req.body.user.name,
        email: req.body.user.email,
        imageUrl: req.body.user.imageUrl,
        role: req.body.user.role,
        balance: req.body.user.balance
      }
      res.status(200).json(user)
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  }

  static logout(req, res, next) {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Successfully logout',
      accountType: req.body.user.accountType
    })
  }
}

==== router index ====
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

// router.get('/', )
router.use('/users', require('./users'))
router.use('/products', require('./product'))
router.use('/transactions', require('./transaction'))

module.exports = router



==== router user ====

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const User = require('../controllers/userController')
const auth = require('../middlewares/auth')

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/register', User.register)
router.post('/login', User.login)
router.get('/', auth.authentication, User.getUser)
router.post('/logout', auth.authentication, User.logout)
module.exports = router


===env===
jwt_key, port, db_uri
```

Comment: Hi semua bisa, welcome. Please consider adding an explanation.